# Flutter :No implementation found issue in path_provider while using get_storage in WorkManager

Tags: flutter

**I am Using the GetStorage plugin With Workmanager and trying to access stored data in the Background its through error**

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

E/flutter (11718): #0      GetStorage._init (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:47:7)

E/flutter (11718): 
E/flutter (11718): #1      new GetStorage._internal. (package:get_storage/src/storage_impl.dart:28:7)
E/flutter (11718): 
E/flutter (11718): #2      callbackDispatcher (package:anganwadimapping/backgroundProcessCallback.dart:8:3)
E/flutter (11718): 
E/flutter (11718):

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way u can get access to local stored with workmanager when the app closed .
U can Explain ur problem maybe we find another way